# generic number of rows for formula excel

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, formula

I am going to import different rows on the same structure from a server or manually via copy and paste to a specific work sheet. THe problem is that number of rows should be able to vary from lets say 1-100.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8990/f6w.png]

As number of rows varies I want to calculate a KPI for every row (the second "box") and then later make a Weighted average in the end. How do enter this into the formulas so they calculate so many rows that i have copied into the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row number that contains `CAPEX values per site (USD)` can be found with [=MATCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php). Subtract from this the number of rows up to `FixCoverage` (could be with another =MATCH but in the example is 4) and add 1 for what may be the start row for your weighted average formulae.

From this deduct however many rows there are above `kUSD` etc and deduct 3. This should give you the number of imported rows.

Add that to the previous result for the row number for the end row for your weighted average formula.